# Angularjs: Ui-select ng-click in ui-select-choices

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

I am trying to use an add button inside the options, but the problem is that ng-click fires but the option is not selected.

```
<ui-select ng-model="datactrl.newservice.selected" theme="selectize" ng-disabled="disabled" style="width: 100%;">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="...">
        <span ng-bind-html="$select.selected.name"></span>          
    </ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="service in data.base_services | filter: $select.search">
        <span ng-bind-html="service.name | highlight: $select.search"></span>

        <!-- HERE NOT -->
        <a href="" class="pull-right" ng-click="setnewservice()">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i>
        </a>    
        <!-- ### -->

    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>                            


<!-- here obviously works -->
<a href="" class="pull-right" ng-click="setnewservice()">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i>
</a>
```

I can send some parameter to the function and handle this case even selecting the clicked link of that item index so the model with take the correct value, 
or like in the above working sample take it outside...

but how can I properly handle this, stop the event, select the option without sending the object or some of its attributes, and then do the rest?

```
$scope.setnewservice = function ($event) {
    $event.stopPropagation();
    // ??
}
```

Comment: I have a similar setup, putting the ng-click as an attribute of us-select-choices both selects the item and calls the method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use ***ng-change*** on the ui-select not ***ng-click*** on the ui-select-choices. Change this:

```
ng-click="setnewservice()
```

to:

```
ui-select ng-model="datactrl.newservice.selected" theme="selectize" ng-disabled="disabled" style="width: 100%;" ng-change="setnewservice()>
```

Comment: I would recommend using on-select vs ng-change especially if you have a typeahead otherwise it will fire on each character typed into select box.

Comment: Sure, if you want to use JavaScript when some text has been selected. But that wasn't what @daniel asked. The ngChange directive is more relevant. The expression is evaluated immediately, unlike the JavaScript event which only triggers at the end of a change. This is needed for ui-select-choices to work. http://embed.plnkr.co/Ufhb0IfzrTlG3XLY2ahh/

Answer (score 0):

You can add the on-select attribute to your  tag like so:

```
on-select="setnewservice($item, $model)"
```